# Alternatives of using user_load_multiple()

Tags: 7

Considering that the parameter `$conditions` of the function [user_load_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_load_multiple/7) has been declared deprecated, if I would keep the code compatible with Drupal 8 code, which Drupal function should I alternatively use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class. It allows to set the query conditions using its methods. The example code in [How to use EntityFieldQuery for Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708) show how a module can build a query for an entity.

```php
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
  ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->fieldCondition('field_news_types', 'value', 'spotlight', '=')
  // See the comment about != NULL above.
  ->fieldCondition('field_photo', 'fid', 'NULL', '!=')
  ->fieldCondition('field_faculty_tag', 'tid', $value)
  ->fieldCondition('field_news_publishdate', 'value', db_like($year) . '%', 'like') // Equal to "starts with"
  ->fieldCondition('field_news_subtitle', 'value', '%' . db_like($year) . '%', 'like') // Equal to "contains"
  ->fieldOrderBy('field_photo', 'fid', 'DESC')
  ->range(0, 10)
  // Run the query as user 1.
  ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1));

$result = $query->execute();
if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $news_items_nids = array_keys($result['node']);
  $news_items = entity_load('node', $news_items_nids);
}
```